Detect current date change in JavaScript
I'm writing a calendar Web application and I'm highlighting current date on the calendar. I want to automatically update which date is highlighted when the actual date changes.
So basically I need a way to have a callback called on midnight. How is it possible? I can imagine naive solution which calculates milliseconds before midnight and calls setTimeout, but I'm not sure how reliable this solution is:

What will happen if browser will put my tab into power-save mode? Will timeout be called after unfreezing the tab given the fact that it will happen after midnight and timeout will miss it's original time?

How to handle timezone/daylight saving changes?


I also can imagine another naive solution which just uses setInterval to have a callback called every second and continuously check current system date. I don't like this approach, because it is power consuming and may make not happy mobile users.

Surely you don't need this to be accurate to the second.  Just do a callback once a minute.

You should assume that the user will change their system date/time while your page is open.

I'd use a long interval (minute or so as suggested), but also use page visibility change to do an immediate check. I can't imagine you'd need to check very often, nobody is going to stare at a calendar for very long around midnight.
